# Print Elements twice side by side when the looping of array ends

Tags: python, python-2.7

I wrote these lines of code

```
import string
alphabets=string.uppercase
for i in range(0,26):
   print alphabets[i]
```

It will print all the alphabets.but if the range is greater than the length of the array

```
for i in range(0,28):
  print alphabets[i]
```

It will give Index out of range error because there are only 26 elements in the Array.

but i want that it should continue looping the array
and print results for the rest of the range after the array has been iterated like this

```
AA
BB
```

So i did this

```
for j in range(0,28-26):
    print alphabets[j]*2
```

but i don't know how to combine these four lines of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import string
alphabets=string.uppercase
for i in range(0, 28):
   print alphabets[i % 26] * (i / 26 + 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(0, 28):
   print alphabets[i%26] * (i/26 + 1)
```

This will work for any value of `i`. It will keep wrapping around and increasing the number of letters printed.

From 50 to 60:

```
YY
ZZ
AAA
BBB
CCC
DDD
EEE
FFF
GGG
HHH
```